# Scala type tags not working as expected

Tags: scala

I have been toying with a pet project that is designed to generate a SQL table based on the fields in a case class, this is done by the case class extending the helper class to expose methods for the wanted functionality.

Most of it is working apart from the type of class, now mind you this is the first time I have worked on anything like this so it is probably the worst way of doing it.

Here is the helper class (`CrateObject.scala`)

```
abstract class CrateObject[T] {

  def create(schema: String)(implicit crateClient: CrateClient): Boolean = {
    if(crateClient == null)
      throw new IOException("Requires implicit object crateClient to be initialized")

    if(exists(schema)(crateClient))
      return false

    val tableName = classOf[T].getSimpleName.toLowerCase
    var tableColumns = Map.empty[String, String]

    classOf[T].getDeclaredFields.foreach { f =>
      f.getType match {
        case t if t == classOf[String]      => tableColumns += f.getName -> "string"
        case t if t == classOf[Int]         => tableColumns += f.getName -> "integer"
        case t if t == classOf[Integer]     => tableColumns += f.getName -> "integer"
        case t if t == classOf[Boolean]     => tableColumns += f.getName -> "boolean"
        case t if t == classOf[Short]       => tableColumns += f.getName -> "short"
        case t if t == classOf[Double]      => tableColumns += f.getName -> "double"
        case t if t == classOf[Array]       => tableColumns += f.getName -> "array"
      }
    }

    val sqlStatement = s"create table $schema.$tableName (${tableColumns.mkString(", ").replace(" ->", "")})"

    try {
      crateClient.sql(sqlStatement)
      true
    }
    catch {
      case ex: Exception =>
        throw new IOException(s"Failed to make table for $schema.$tableName", ex)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I have been getting is on `classOf[T]` which is failing with `class type required but T found`

Is this because I am doing this the wrong way (if so, what is the right way?) or because of something else I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head it seems I have found a solution that I should of seen ages ago, because the helper class is an `abstract class` it means that calling `getClass` returns the class of extender class.

TL;DR

All I had to do was replace `classOf[T]` with `this.getClass`. The type tag `T` is left where it is though because it is used in another method

This is the complete version of what I was working on https://gist.github.com/LiamHaworth/6fda3836227b8ecd2206

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you want to have a generic T. Try with something like this (using ClassTag):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag    
abstract class CrateObject[T](implicit classTag: ClassTag[T]) {
    def create(schema: String)(implicit crateClient: CrateClient): Boolean = {
        ...
        classTag.getClass // instead of classOf[T] use classTag.getClass
        ...
    }
}
```